# When I used nodejs sdk to translate file is failed

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

When I used nodejs sdk to translate file is failed.

I uploaded the ifc file already. And I use nodejs SDK - ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi to translate " ifc " to " svf ". But when I check the job process ,I got " TranslationWorker-InternalFailure " error.

According to the sdk reference[(forge sdk for nodejs on github )](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate). My post body is:

```
{
"input":{
  "urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Ym9pbGVyL2JyaWRnZTIuaWZj"
},
"output":{
    "formats":[{
        "type":"svf",
        "views":["2d","3d"]
    }]
}
```

When I used postman to call "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest" api.It response me:

```
{
"Result": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "date": "Tue, 06 Mar 2018 09:16:00 GMT",
        "x-ads-app-identifier": "platform-viewing-2018.01.02.49.b4217d5-production",
        "x-ads-duration": "212 ms",
        "x-ads-startup-time": "Mon Feb 26 02:55:52 UTC 2018",
        "content-length": "439",
        "connection": "Close"
    },
    "body": {
        "type": "manifest",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "failed",
        "progress": "complete",
        "region": "US",
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Ym9pbGVyL2JyaWRnZTIuaWZj",
        "version": "1.0",
        "derivatives": [
            {
                "name": "bridge2.ifc",
                "hasThumbnail": "false",
                "status": "failed",
                "progress": "complete",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "type": "error",
                        "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829",
                        "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                    }
                ],
                "outputType": "svf"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I used postman to call " https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job " api 
 to translate is successed.

what different the api and the sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using to translate using the NPM

```
var translateFile = function(encodedURN){
logs(chalk.bold.green("**** Translating file derivative"));
var postJob =
{
    input: {
        urn: encodedURN
    },
    output: {
        formats: [
            {
                type: "svf",
                views: ["2d", "3d"]
            }
        ]
    }
};

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    derivativesApi.translate(postJob, {}, oAuth2TwoLegged, oAuth2TwoLegged.getCredentials()).then(
        function(res){
            resolve(res);
        },function(err){
            reject(err);
        }
    )   
});
};
```

And if you want to test it also I have a Node Uploader sample using the NPM calls to do the whole process.

https://github.com/jaimerosales/modelderivative-nodejs-tutorial

Comment: Thanks!! It works for me. My file seems Damage. And I have to use uploadChunk not uploadObject. The original problem is "upload phase" not "translate phase".